# boost::ptr_vector<>::iterator is it possible to loop it use while?

Tags: c++, boost

is it possible?

like this:

```
    while(itr!=list.end())
    {

        ++itr; //is it ok?
    }
```

instead of:

```
for(itr=list.begin();itr!=list.end();++itr)
```

I guess it's just a personal favor but I prefer while a little bit more. thanks

Comment: If you can use C++11, try the [range-based for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for_loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for`-loop of the flavor:

```
for(init-stmt; test-expression; alter-stmt)
{
    // code
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
init-stmt;
while (test-expression)
{
    //code
    alter-stmt
}
```

Provided your init-stmt logic is identical in preamble to your while-loop as that of your for-loop, there is no issue to be concerned about. In your case, it would appear as this:

```
itr = list.begin();
while (itr != list.end())
{
    // code
    ++itr;
}
```

---

**Variable Lifetime**

It is worth noting the *lifetime* of the variables declared in the `init-stmt` can make these different. For example:

```
for (auto itr = list.begin(); itr != list.end(); ++itr)
{
    // code
}
```

The variable `itr` has no lifetime outside the loop. To have an equivalent `while`-loop entails using a scope-wrapping set of braces:

```
{
    auto itr = list.begin()
    while (itr != list.end())
    {
        // code
        ++itr;
    }
}
```

Finally, as others have suggested, perhaps a ranged-for-loop construct may better suit your needs. If interested, you can read more about it [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `itr=list.begin()` before that while loop, it's fine.